# Google Analytics tracking un-configured events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dom-events, google-analytics-firebase

We have been facing strange concerns with google analytics. Its tracking few unconfigured events.

Event labels as Logs , Jobs, Job etc.

Are these events tracked by GA by default? Not sure only for few pages its tracking or it is added from client end.. Is there a way to overcome it?

I have checked all the pages and code for this events is absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be from someone messing around in the console, somebody using your account ID, or code that you've missed / conditionally triggers. Go into the Behavior > Events > Top Events, select your event label you question, and then in the report add a secondary dimension of "Page". This will show you all the pages that event label occurred on.